# How can I save audio from a MediaStreamAudioSourceNode to an AudioBuffer with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, audio-streaming, webrtc, web-audio-api

New to working with audio, I'm trying to save the audio captured by the microphone. Here's what I have so far:

```
record = function() {
  navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({
    audio: true
  }, onStream, onError);
};

onStream = function(stream) {
  var microphone = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
  // save audio from microphone to an AudioBuffer 
};
```

There must be some way to append to the AudioBuffer as data is streamed in. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How will we use the below answer for sending arraybuffer through binaryjs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup. Check out [RecorderJS](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs). Super easy to use.